# Which uniform is this soldier wearing?

Tags: 19th-century, identification, uniform

[image: head and shoulders of a man in dark uniform with gold braid, high collar, lots of gold shoulder braid]I think this uniform could be from the hussars, possibly 1800s. I have examined pages from the Imperial War Museum but had no luck.

Comment: [This](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/1911_Encyclop%C3%A6dia_Britannica/Uniforms) is a great source of descriptions.

Comment: Judging from the hair and facial adornment, this is probably from the post-Napoleonic era, by which time one did not see single epaulettes.  Although we’re seeing this gent from the right side, I would suspect that the epaulette, which probably has a match on his left shoulder, would probably get in the way of a hussar’s typical pelisse, a short jacket worn open and draped over, usually, the left shoulder.  I don’t think he is a hussar.